# For loop Xarray (NetCDF) - how to append results of for loop to existing dataset

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

Very new to python/coding and trying to work with NetCDF data via xarray. Essential I'm trying to work with climate model data to compare future projections to historical values to get a % reduction in a snow ('snw') to show projected trends/losses on a series of maps.

So far I've created a for loop that iterates through the time, latitude, and longitude dimensions, and then subtracts the projected snow values from the historic snow values. I've created a small subset of the original data that only considers one time slice each, and only includes the western US.

```
def get_diff_snw(hist_avg, proj_value):
    return proj_value - hist_avg

for i, time in enumerate(ds_ssp_subset['snw']):
    # For each time, iterate through the latitudes    
    for j, lat in enumerate(time):
        # For each latitude, iterate through the longitudes
        for k, lon in enumerate(lat):
            print(
                get_diff_snw(
                    ds_hr4_running_subset['snw'][i, j, k].values,
                    lon.values,
                )
            )
```

For reference: ssp is the future projections and hr4 is the historical dataset.

This spits out a list (I think?) of the difference between historical average and projected values:

```
1.5503063
3.0794563
-3.578083
-2.1282718
-1.0593466
-0.043488864
-0.10155213
-0.2542992
-0.63282454
-0.3104693
...
```

I'd like to add to the historical dataset, and ensure that these values are still associated with their respective coordinates. I can't seem to figure this out, any help is appreciated!

Comment: sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're not understanding :S are you not sure what the difference between a print statement and a list is? or is there a part of your code we're not seeing? what do you mean when you say you'd like to add to the historical dataset?

Comment: also, as far as I can tell, you're just subtracting the longitude from the snowfall amounts, which doesn't make any sense. to subtract a mean climatology from a projection, do something along the lines of `ds_ssp_subset['snw'] - ds_ssp_subset['snw'].sel(time=slice(1986, 2005)).mean(dim="time")` or something like this. See the [user guide section on computation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html) for more of an overview.

Comment: but if you're just barely starting with python, you're really jumping in the deep end and stack overflow isn't the right place to go for help. I'd strongly suggest starting with a python course, and once you're done with that, go through the [xarray tutorials](https://tutorial.xarray.dev/intro.html) webpage to get a good grounding.